# Find vectors to satisfy given dimensions of subspace spanned by 24 vectors that are rearrangements of 4-tuples.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a homework exercise that I am having a difficult time understanding/visualizing:

Choose $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$. It has $24$ rearrangements like $(x_2, x_1, x_3, x_4)$ and $(x_4, x_3, x_1, x_2)$. Those $24$ vectors including $x$ itself span a subspace $S$. Find specific vectors $x$ so that dimension of $S$ is $0$, $1$, $3$, $4$.

I appreciate any help that can be given. Thanks! Source: 3.5.42, P183, *Intro to Lin Alg*, by G Strang

Comment: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=154832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ is easy, not much choice.

As to $1$, think of a nonzero vector that doesn't change when rearranged.

As to $4$, think of the standard basis.

As to $3$, think of the subspace $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4= 0$.

Comment: I think I have an understanding of when S=0,1 and 4, but I am not sure what to do for S=3

Comment: @user42864, pick a nonzero element in that subspace, and see what you can do with the vectors you obtain by rearranging it. Please let me know if you can do it.

Comment: When I visualize this problem, I feel that I should be working with the column spaces of x1, x2, etc in R4. Am I correct?

Comment: Never mind. I've got it.

Comment: @user42864: Could it please be elucidated, in Andreas Caranti's answer and not as a comment, whether the dimension of $S$ can be $2$? I'd appreciate it !

Comment: @LePressentiment, well, you already linked to a perfectly satisfactory answer in your comment to OP. That answer shows that if $U$ is a subspace which is invariant under $S_{4}$, and $U$ contains a vector which is not a non-zero multiple of $(1,1,1,1)$, then $U$ contains the $3$-dimensional subspace given by $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 0$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Thank you. What's $S_4, U$ in your previous comment? I'm confounded by StatusX's last answer there, where he writes: (difference of two permutations of $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4))\cdot(1, 1, 1, 1) = 0$. How does this divulge if $\dim S = 2$ or not?

Comment: @LePressentiment, $S_4$ is the symmetric group on four letters, and $U$ is just a name for a subspace.